# Problems with syncdb after creating Heroku Django app

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

I'm setting up a Django app on Heroku using the https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django tutorial and I'm running into the below error running `heroku run python manage.py syncdb`

```
ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.
```

I get the same error when syncing locally. I've read all the threads on StackOverflow but nothing has solved this issue. Relevant parts of settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': '',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        # The following settings are not used with sqlite3:
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',                      # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or '127.0.0.1' for localhost through TCP.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default.
    }
}


import dj_database_url
DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()

# Honor the 'X-Forwarded-Proto' header for request.is_secure()
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

# Allow all host headers
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

# Static asset configuration
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
```

Comment: Error is so clear. You have not specified the backend database, and the correct credentials. in `DATABASES` settings

Comment: @karthikr  I've tried different options for the settings.py however, in the tutorial, it doesn't specify they be filled out so I'm not sure what they should be! Can you help?

Comment: [Here follow this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/#database-setup)

Comment: @karthikr thanks, i've tried that and get the same error

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure why the tutorial glosses over this - I've seen similar question crop up frequently - but here are the steps I've taken that resolved the issue. It's worth reading the Postgres documentation as well - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql

1) Create a Postgres DB using `heroku addons | grep POSTGRES` in terminal

2) Connect the DB to the app - `heroku addons:add heroku-postgresql:dev`

3) Promote the URL to Database URL: `heroku pg:promote HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_RED_URL`

4) Add this into your settings.py:

`DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config(default=os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL'))`

Answer (score -1):

In your settings put that:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',  # Or another database
        'NAME': 'database.db',                      
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',                      
        'PORT': '',                      
    }
}
```

Comment: This is using sqlite3 - am trying to setup Postgres

Comment: Well, put Postgres then

Comment: see my solution below